# Variável retornando valor que foi declarado incialmente e não o que o usuário informou

Tags: python, algoritmo

```
cont = soma = maiorv = media = 0
r = 'S'
menorv = 0
while r in 'Ss':
    n = int(input('Informe um número inteiro: '))
    cont += 1
    soma += n
    if n == 1:
        maiorv = menorv = n
    else:
        if n > maiorv:
            maiorv = n
        if n < menorv:
            menorv = n
    r = str(input('Quer continuar: (S/N) ')).upper().strip()[0]
media = soma/cont
print('\nA média entre os valores é {}'.format(media))
print('O maior valor é {} e o menor valor é {}'.format(maiorv, menorv))
```

Nessa última linha do `print`, o valor que retorna no `menorv` está sendo `0` ao invés do menor valor que o usuário digitou, alguém sabe me explicar porquê?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinto informar que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468205/112052) (que foi apagada) está errada. Por exemplo, se você digitar os números 3, 2 e 1, nesta ordem, o resultado é:

```
O maior valor é 1 e o menor valor é 1
```

O código era esse:

```
cont = soma = maiorv = media = 0
r = 'S'
menorv = 0
while r in 'Ss':
    n = int(input('Informe um número inteiro: '))
    if cont == 0:
        menorv = n
    cont += 1
    soma += n
    if n == 1:
        maiorv = menorv = n
    else:
        if n > maiorv:
            maiorv = n
        if n < menorv:
            menorv = n
    r = str(input('Quer continuar: (S/N) ')).upper().strip()[0]
media = soma/cont
print('\nA média entre os valores é {}'.format(media))
print('O maior valor é {} e o menor valor é {}'.format(maiorv, menorv))
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/byRPSr) o código rodando.</sup>

Ele diz - erroneamente - que o maior valor é 1. Isso acontece por causa deste `if`:

```
if n == 1:
    maiorv = menorv = n
```

Ou seja, se o usuário digitar `1`, ele passa a ser o maior **e** o menor. E se o `1` for o último número digitado, é como se todos os números anteriores fossem ignorados. Não faz sentido ter esse `if`. Aliás, ele também daria errado para o menor, se anteriormente tivesse sido digitado um número negativo, por exemplo.

E uma alternativa para a solução proposta (ver se `count` é 0) é inicializar `maiorv` com o menor número possível (assim, qualquer valor que for digitado será com certeza maior que ele), e `menorv` com o maior valor possível (assim qualquer valor digitado será menor que ele). Uma opção é usar os "infinitos" positivo e negativo, aí você elimina a necessidade desses `if`'s, mantendo só o essencial:

```
cont = soma = 0
maiorv = -float('inf') # infinito negativo
menorv = float('inf') # infinito
while True:
    n = int(input('Informe um número inteiro: '))
    cont += 1
    soma += n
    if n > maiorv:
        maiorv = n
    if n < menorv:
        menorv = n
    if input('Quer continuar: (S/N) ').upper().strip()[0] != 'S':
        break # sai do while

print('\nA média entre os valores é {}'.format(soma / cont))
print('O maior valor é {} e o menor valor é {}'.format(maiorv, menorv))
```

Também fiz um *loop* infinito (`while True`) que só é interrompido se digitar algo diferente de "S". Repare também que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário.

E eliminei a variável `media`, pois se você só precisa imprimir e depois não vai usar o valor para mais nada, nem precisa dela. O mesmo vale para a variável `r`, eliminei e usei direto o retorno de `input` no `if`. E como você usa [`upper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) para converter em maiúscula, não precisa comparar se é igual a "s" minúsculo. O detalhe é que se digitar qualquer coisa diferente de "S", ele sai do `while` (não verifica se foi digitado apenas "S" ou "N").

---

Não é o foco da pergunta, mas o código não valida se foi digitado um número válido. Se quiser incluir esta validação, basta fazer outro *loop* que pede para digitar novamente enquanto não for um número.

E se estiver usando Python >= 3.6, pode trocar `format` por [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
cont = soma = 0
maiorv = -float('inf') # infinito negativo
menorv = float('inf') # infinito
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input('Informe um número inteiro: '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Você não digitou um número inteiro')
    cont += 1
    soma += n
    if n > maiorv:
        maiorv = n
    if n < menorv:
        menorv = n
    if input('Quer continuar: (S/N) ').upper().strip()[0] != 'S':
        break # sai do while

# usando f-string em vez de format (Python >= 3.6)
print(f'\nA média entre os valores é {soma / cont}')
print(f'O maior valor é {maiorv} e o menor valor é {menorv}')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela correção em alguns aspectos, tô começando agora a programar então ainda tenho muita coisa a aprender kk. esse "infinitos" que utilizou é como se o valor que declarei fosse infinito e quando o usuário digitar um valor irá substituir esse infinito?

Comment: @VictorHenrique A ideia é que se `maiorv` começa com "infinito negativo", então qualquer valor que for digitado será maior que ele (ou seja, na primeira iteração, com certeza entrará no `if n > maiorv` (porque qualquer número é maior que infinito negativo). É só para evitar o `if cont == 0`, que apesar de funcionar eu acho desnecessário. E a mesma lógica vale para `menorv`: ele começa com infinito, então qualquer valor que for digitado será menor que ele

Comment: entendi agora, e o outro infinito segue a mesma lógica só que positivo? é, tem coisas que depois de prontas notamos que é desnecessário, como tô no inicio diversos códigos que faço ainda tenho que fazer uma correção posteriormente

Comment: eu não sabia que tava errada, quando li de primeira e efetuei o teste pra mim estava certo. Perdão pelo erro

Comment: @VictorHenrique "*outro infinito segue a mesma lógica só que positivo*" - exatamente! `menorv`  começa com o valor "infinito", então qualquer valor que for digitado será menor que ele. Quanto ao erro, tudo bem, acontece :-) Fica a lição de que temos que testar bem nosso código, muitas vezes tem casos que podem dar errado e que a gente não pensa na hora...